# xgboost set up in R

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to use xgboost in R but I am not sure what the inputs into the model need to be. The code I have for the model is:

```
xgb <- xgboost(data = data.matrix(training[,-1]), 
                           label = labels, 
                           eta = 0.1,
                           max_depth = 15, 
                           nround=25, 
                           subsample = 0.5,
                           colsample_bytree = 0.5,
                           seed = 1,
                           eval_metric = "merror",
                           objective = "binary:logistic",
                           num_class = 12,
                           nthread = 3
            )
```

I get the following error:

> Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) :    The length
>   of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data

My label is the column I am trying to predict but the input data is all the input variables. For example, the dim of the labels shows [1] 1837 1 and the dim of the training table is [1] 1837 8 so I thought that these didn't have to be the same size? The labels column is set to be true or false as I thought that this was the format needed. The column that has the true or false is the last column in the training data so hence why I use the dimension of training,[-1].

Could someone please explain what the rest of the inputs are as I have copied this code from an example online and I don't understand what is needed.

Comment: It means that `length(labels) != dim(training)[1]`, Are you sure your dependent variable is present in the environment which is named as "labels" ?

Comment: 'labels' or the dependent variable is one column with 1837 rows of either True or False and R is giving me the dimension [1] 1837    1. The first column of the training dataset has the same dimensions: [1] 1837    1

Comment: You labels are binary, correct? I think in XGB you need to use 0 and 1 instead of TRUE or FALSE, but I could be mistaken. Also, why are you using num_class = 12? If your data is binary this should give a different error, but I would try changing it aswell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I have tried both 0 and 1 and TRUE and FALSE as the dependent variable and both give the same error (i.e. the one I copied above with the length of labels not equally the number of rows of the input). As for why i am using num_class = 12 - I have no idea - as I said above I just copied that code from a website without understanding what some of them mean. I also commented out the num_class = 12 and it made no difference to the error.